# Refused to execute script MIME type checking is enabled?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

I keep getting this error on console.:

*"Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/js/main.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."*

I tried every way I could find on the internet and none of them worked. I shared my codes on code snippet. I want my sign up form to direct me to home page but it doesnt direct me anywhere. It just giving me error on console. I shared my index.js adminRoutes.js and indexRoutes.js codes with you. I used mongodb nodejs and express.js on this project. I just want to click sign up and I want it to direct me to home page which is defined as /

**I can add more codes if its necessary.**

indexRoutes.js:

```
const express = require('express'),
router = express.Router();



//ARRAY

let data= [
    {
        postTitle: "Blog Denemesi",
        postSubtitle: "Bu ilk blog denemesi ve video çok sıkıcı.",
        image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564177611049-76e2933c6017?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=464&q=80"

    },

    {
        postTitle: "Testing a blog",
        postSubtitle: "This is a blog testing",
        image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552664730-d307ca884978?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80"

    },

    {
        postTitle: "Test Test",
        postSubtitle: "Lets see whats gonna happen",
        image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562762394-3acfba62a48e?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80"

    },




]


//ARRAY Bitiş

router.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    res.render('home' , {data : data});
 }) ;

 router.get("/about", (req,res)=>{
    res.render('about');
 }) ;

 router.get("/contact", (req,res)=>{
    res.render('contact');
 }) ;



module.exports = router;
```

adminRoutes.js:

```
const express = require('express'),
passport = require("passport"),
User= require('../models/userModel'),
router = express.Router();


//ARRAY

let adminActions =[

    {
        actionId:1,
        actionName: "changeHomeImage",
        displayName: "Change Home Image"

    },
    {
        actionId:2,
        actionName: "changeAboutImage",
        displayName: "Change About Image"

    },
    {
        actionId:3,
        actionName: "changeAboutText",
        displayName: "Change About Text"

    },
    {
        actionId:4,
        actionName: "addNewBlog",
        displayName: "Add New Blog"

    },
    {
        actionId:5,
        actionName: "listAllBlogs",
        displayName: "List All Blogs"

    }
];

//ARRAY Bitiş

router.get("/admin", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("admin/admin",{adminActions:adminActions});
 }) ;

 router.get("/signin", (req,res)=>{
    res.render("admin/signin");
 }) ;

 router.post("/signin", (req,res)=>{
 }) ;

 router.get("/signup", (req,res)=>{
    res.render('admin/signup');
 }) ;

 router.post("/signup", (req,res)=>{
   
    let newUser = new User({username:req.body.username});
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, (err, user)=>{
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/signup");
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, ()=>{
            res.redirect("/");

        });
    })
}) ;

module.exports = router;
```

index.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    express= require ("express"),
    passport = require("passport"),
    LocalStrategy = require("passport-local"),
    User= require("./models/userModel"),
    expressSession = require("express-session"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),

    app = express();

const { Passport } = require("passport");
    //Routes

    const indexRoutes = require("./routes/indexRoutes");
          adminRoutes = require("./routes/adminRoutes");



    //App Config

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/BlogApp");
app.set('view engine' , 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

//Passport Config

app.use(require("express-session")({
     secret: "bu güvenlik cümlesi",
     resave: false,
     saveUninitialized: false

}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());


//Routes Using

app.use(indexRoutes);
app.use(adminRoutes);

//Server 

const server = app.listen(3000, (err)=> {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }

      console.log('App Started. Port number  : %d ', server.address().port);

})
```

signup.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Clean Blog - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
        <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.3.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Google fonts-->

        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!--OLDU MU EMİN DEĞİLİM-->

        <!--Bootstrap Link-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!--Bootstrap FONTAWESOME-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.1/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-QYIZto+st3yW+o8+5OHfT6S482Zsvz2WfOzpFSXMF9zqeLcFV0/wlZpMtyFcZALm" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!--JQuery CDN-->
        <script
           src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js"
           integrity="sha256-a9jBBRygX1Bh5lt8GZjXDzyOB+bWve9EiO7tROUtj/E="
           crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

           <style>
            #mainNav .navbar-brand{
                color: black;
            }
            #mainNav .navbar-brand:hover{
                color: coral;




            }
            #mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a{
                color: black;
                background-color: black;
                
                
            }
            #mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a:hover{
                color: coral;

            }
           </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Navigation-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Start Bootstrap</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    Menu
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="/about">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-lg-3 py-3 py-lg-4" href="/signin">Sign In</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 5%;">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Sign Up Form</h1>
    <h3 style="text-align: center; color: red;">ADMIN</h3>
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>

</div>

<%- include ('../partials/footer') %>
```

main.js:

```
/*!
* Start Bootstrap - Clean Blog v6.0.9 (https://startbootstrap.com/theme/clean-blog)
* Copyright 2013-2023 Start Bootstrap
* Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-clean-blog/blob/master/LICENSE)
*/
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let scrollPos = 0;
    const mainNav = document.getElementById('mainNav');
    const headerHeight = mainNav.clientHeight;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        const currentTop = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top * -1;
        if ( currentTop < scrollPos) {
            // Scrolling Up
            if (currentTop > 0 && mainNav.classList.contains('is-fixed')) {
                mainNav.classList.add('is-visible');
            } else {
                console.log(123);
                mainNav.classList.remove('is-visible', 'is-fixed');
            }
        } else {
            // Scrolling Down
            mainNav.classList.remove(['is-visible']);
            if (currentTop > headerHeight && !mainNav.classList.contains('is-fixed')) {
                mainNav.classList.add('is-fixed');
            }
        }
        scrollPos = currentTop;
    });
})
```

Comment: You keep getting WHAT error, and on which line, exactly?

Comment: @TimRoberts I keep getting " Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/js/main.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. " error in signup on console

Comment: This error is usually thrown when the `response`'s `Content-type` does not fit the `request`s OR when the a file does not exist. What does `app.get("views")` log on the console? Default path of `.ejs` are under  `path.join(process.cwd(),"views")`. Are your view files located under "$CWD/views/admin", "$CWD/views/home" etc?

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin no they are located in views folder

Comment: views/admin/admin.ejs and views/blog/newBlog.ejs etc. @ibrahimtanyalcin

Comment: I do not know how the rendering engine processes `ejs` files but looking at the `signup.ejs`, the `form` element is missing action attribute such as `<form action="/signup" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ...` If the rendering engine does not add these by default your request is going to `/` which you have no middleware attached, and hence no `text/html` to process.

Comment: Where is `main.js` being referenced?  I don't see it.

Comment: @TimRoberts im new at coding so I dont understand what do you mean. Do I supposed to reference it somewhere? How can I do it?

Comment: What should i write instead x-www-form-urlencoded @ibrahimtanyalcin

Comment: So have you copied this all from somewhere?  The error is complaining about "main.js", so SOMEONE is trying to load it.

Comment: I didnt copy it from anywhere else @TimRoberts

Comment: I just noticed what you meant. Referance for main.js is in the footer section @TimRoberts

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by writing down how to do it in case someone will face the same error.

1. Move js folder to the public folder
2. Write the code belove in `signup.ejs`:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("adminSignup").onsubmit = (e) => {
       console.log("dsadsa");
       e.preventDefault();
       window.location.href = "/";
    };
</script>
```

3. Give form an ID:

```html
<form id="adminSignup">
```

4. Add in index.js

```js
app.use(express.static('js'));
```

Thats all! Now your code is ready to work!